# Correlation analysis of proteins to clinical variables of individuals

Tags: correlation

I want to do a correlation analysis of proteins to a clinical variable.

e.g.  correlation of a protein to weight

For many individuals I have:
4 time points with different weights 
4 protein intensities.

I can now make correlation tests and will get p-values for proteins for individuals

Person A: 
Protein 1 p=0.1
Protein 2 p=0.01
...

Person B:
Protein 1 p=0.2
Protein 2 p=0.3
...

...

How can I calculate, if Protein 1 correlates significantly within the whole data set with weight? I have now as many p-values as individuals for every protein?

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer myself.

a t-test with p-values from the correlations.

The null hypothesis: $H_0= $ pvalue $\geq 0.05$